# Why does jquery UI draggable not work with getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I thought the 2 were the same.

```
$("#SomeId")
```

and

```
document.getElementById("SomeId")
```

I assume I am wrong because the following works

```
$("#SomeId").draggable();
```

Where as neither of these do

```
document.getElementById("SomeId").draggable();
```

or

```
var x = document.getElementById("SomeId");
x.draggable();
```

My question is what is the difference here? Is JQuery doing some trickery and registering in such a way that only elements chosen via JQuery can work with JqueryUI?

So far my project has been only vanilla Javascript but now I must use JQuery and so I'm migrating. I know how to work around this and have a few ideas for fixes but my question is about *why* this doesn't work as understanding is more important.

Comment: because it is part of jQuery, not the DOM...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work because the jquery selector gets more than just the element. It returns a jquery object, allowing you to do jquery-ee stuff to them, like `.draggable()`.

If you want to use the javascript `getElementById()` method, you can make it work if you were to change your example above to:

```
var x = document.getElementById("SomeId");
$(x).draggable();
```

Which will turn the plain javascript object into a jquery object.

If you console.log() both the jquery object, and the js dom object separately, you'll see they are very different.

Comment: I had no idea... and will investigate as you suggested.

Comment: Is there an efficiency loss or gain by doing this?

Comment: I haven't tested, but my guess is not. I'm almost certain that the jquery selector uses the standard js selector when a string is passed in. And so when you just pass in the element instead, all it has to do is return the jquery object with that element as part of it. So either way, you'd be doing one dom lookup, and one jquery return. If I had to pick one over the other, I'd assume going straight for the jqeury selector would be more efficient, if not just because it'll execute one less line of code. Plus it's more readable.